# How do I configure JDK on Android Studio?

Tags: android

I only recently started with Android App development and when I opened up my first project, it give me the following errors:

error(3, 22)
- Download JDK 7
- Select a JDK from the File System
- Open build.grade File

I have downloaded JDK 8, but did not resolve the issue. I don't want to start my first project with this handing in the air.

Any idea how I can get rid of this message.

Comment: *Any idea how I can get rid of this message* Downloading JDK 7 ?

Comment: which jdk so u have like 7 0r 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click "Select a JDK from the File System", then select your JDK folder.